# How to import JAR application into other project, and start it as new process from JVM?

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, dependency-management

I have two projects - A and B, they are in separate git repos.

Project A is a gradle+kotlin application with its own dependencies.

Project B is a gradle+kotlin testing suite. It wants to import Project A and start it new process like this:

```
val command = ArrayList<String>()
    command.add(javaBin)   // from java.home + path to java bin
    command.addAll(jvmArgs)// user-specified args, usually empty
    command.add("-cp")
    command.add(classpath) // from java.class.path
    command.add(className) // projectA.ClassWithMain
    command.addAll(args)   // user-specified args, usually empty
```

([source](https://lankydan.dev/running-a-kotlin-class-as-a-subprocess))

When I simply add jar via jitpack.io, *the process starts*, shows signs of life (prints internal logs) and then almost immediately fails with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.Table.text$default(Lorg/jetbrains/exposed/sql/Table;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;ZILjava/lang/Object;)Lorg/jetbrains/exposed/sql/Column;
```

Note that Project A has this in dependecies:

```
    implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed:exposed-jdbc:$exposedVersion")
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It seems your `classpath` is missing some dependencies. How do you construct/retrieve that value?

Comment: @JoachimSauer you mean `command`? I posted a link (source) below the code snippet. In short - I build this command, and then `ProcessBuilder(command).start()`

Comment: No, I wrote `classpath` and I mean the variable `classpath` which defines which libraries the new JVM process should consider. How do you get that value? Are you sure it contains all libraries that Process A requires?

Comment: I saw the comment about "from `java.class.path`". If that's from the system property then I've got bad news for you: that only works if you want to start something that requires the exact same libraries that are running right now (i.e. if you basically want to start another process of the same project).

Comment: @JoachimSauer is there anything I can do to add libs from classpath of Project A into Project B?